# Grouping by date difference/range

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-iq

How would i write a statement that would make specific group by's looking at the monthly date range/difference. Example:

```
org_group | date | second_group_by

 A      30.10.2013     1
 A      29.11.2013     1
 A      31.12.2013     1
 A      30.01.2015     2
 A      27.02.2015     2
 A      31.03.2015     2
 A      30.04.2015     2
```

as long es there isnt a monthly `date_diff > 1` it should be in the same second_group_by. I hope its clear enough for you to understand, the column second_group_by should be generated by the user...it doesnt exists in the table.

Answer (score 1):

date diff between which rows though?
If you just want to separate years (or months or weeks) use 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(....)

That's Sybase or SQL Server but other SQLs will have equivalent.

If you have specific data ranges, get them into a table with start and end date-time and a monotonically increasing integer, join to that with a BETWEEN and GROUP BY the integer.